# Gitlab + GKE + Gitlab CI unable to clone Repository

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to user GitLab CI with GKE cluster to execute pipelines. I have the experience using Docker runner, but GKE is still pretty new to me, here's what I did:

1. Create GKE cluster via Project settings in GitLab.
2. Install Helm Tiller via GitLab Project settings.
3. Install GitLab Runner via GitLab Project settings.
4. Create gitlab-ci.yml with the following content
       before_script:
         - php -v

   ```
   standard:
     image: falnyr/php-ci-tools:php-cs-fixer-7.0
     script:
       - php-cs-fixer fix --diff --dry-run --stop-on-violation -v --using-cache=no

   lint:7.1:
     image: falnyr/php-ci:7.1-no-xdebug
     script:
       - composer build
       - php vendor/bin/parallel-lint --exclude vendor .

   cache:
     paths:
       - vendor/
   ```
5. Push commit to the repository
6. Pipeline output is following

   ```
   Running with gitlab-runner 10.3.0 (5cf5e19a)
     on runner-gitlab-runner-666dd5fd55-h5xzh (04180b2e)
   Using Kubernetes namespace: gitlab-managed-apps
   Using Kubernetes executor with image falnyr/php-ci:7.1-no-xdebug ...
   Waiting for pod gitlab-managed-apps/runner-04180b2e-project-5-concurrent-0nmpp7 to be running, status is Pending
   Running on runner-04180b2e-project-5-concurrent-0nmpp7 via runner-gitlab-runner-666dd5fd55-h5xzh...
   Cloning repository...
   Cloning into '/group/project'...
   remote: You are not allowed to download code from this project.
   fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@git.domain.tld/group/project.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
   ERROR: Job failed: error executing remote command: command terminated with non-zero exit code: Error executing in Docker Container: 1
   ```

Now I think that I should add a gitlab-ci-token user with password somewhere, not sure if it is supposed to work like this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading more about the topic it seems that pipelines should be executed via HTTPS only (not SSH).

I enabled the HTTPS communication and when I execute the pipeline as the user in the project (admin that is not added to the project throws this error) it works without a problem.